# Preserve HTML tags inside window.getselection when removing the selection

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, syntax-highlighting

I have some code that allows the user to highlight the text. It then saves this highlighted text to a database so when the user comes back to the page it is still there. I am running into an issue when the user wants to remove the highlight. If there is an HTML tag inside the selected text the tag gets removed. I would like it to not remove any html tags other than the span tag for the highlight.

Everything works great except for the removal.

example:

```
<p id="SOMEID">Paragraph text <span class="highlight">Highlighted text <em>Some highlighted text</em> some more highlighted text </span> more paragraph text</p>
```

Here is my code:

```
surroundSelection(action) {
    var span = document.createElement("span")
    
    if(action == 'highlight')
        span.className = 'highlighted'

    var sel = window.getSelection()
    
    if(action == 'remove') {
        let ancestor = sel.anchorNode.parentNode.parentNode
        let parent = sel.anchorNode.parentElement
        
        ancestor.insertBefore(sel.anchorNode, parent)
        sel.anchorNode.remove()
    }
    if (window.getSelection) {
        
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var range = this.selectedRange.cloneRange()
        
            if(action == 'highlight')
                range.surroundContents(span)

            sel.removeAllRanges()
            sel.addRange(range)
        }
    }
    this.saveHighlight(sel, action)
},
```

Here is a Fiddle to demonstrate the problem. Select some text that includes PART of the `<em>` but not all of it.

For example select: `wasted. “Not that I seek the gift itself, but I seek for the profit which increases to your account” (Philippians`

Then click on the highlight popup.

NOTE: After the text is highlighted, If you try to select any part of the highlighted `<em>` it will show the **Highlight** popup again even though the text is already highlighted.

For this example select **wasted** and it will give you the option to **Remove** the highlight. Once you click the Remove, notice that all of that text is now missing from the paragraph.

https://jsfiddle.net/jsd219/o1p9xqv2/16/

Here is a video demonstrating the issue
https://vimeo.com/792657816/2d6cb5fa9c

Comment: Can you produce a working fiddle that can explain like when are you calling this `surroundSelection` method, how are you selecting the text and triggering the action same time?

Comment: @NehaSoni Sorry for the delay... I have a fiddle posted now with instructions on how to repeat the issue

Comment: If I am correct, this issue is also happening with non-HTML selection. I mean, if you first select, `writing was not to encourage` and highlight it, and then you only want to unhighlight the `not to encourage` then the whole highlight sentence will get unhighlighted.

Comment: @NehaSoni Sorry, I might not have been clear. Yes the code is written so that if the user selects part of the highlighted text and clicks the remove button it will remove the full highlight. That part is correct. The issue I have is when the User selects text that includes the childnode (in this case the em) and then when they go to remove the highlight it removes all of the text with it

Comment: @NehaSoni I just added a video above demonstrating my issue

Comment: Hey, try commenting the code `sel.anchorNode.remove()` in the method `surroundSelection`. If this works let me know, I have other questions.

Comment: @NehaSoni That removes the highlight from the selected text only but not the entire highlight.

Comment: @NehaSoni Basically I just want the span tag removed but leave everything else